# where is KF5/inserthtmldialog.h at ubuntu disco?

Tags: compiling

Upto cosmic, KF5's inserthtmldialog.h exists here :

c++ : /usr/include/KF5/KPIMTextEdit/KPIMTextEdit/InsertHtmlDialog

c : /usr/include/KF5/KPIMTextEdit/kpimtextedit/inserthtmldialog.h

But I couldn't find the file for disco.

Instead of KF5 version of inserthtmldialog.h, inserthtmldialog.h is installed at /usr/include/kpimtextedit/inserthtmldialog.h by installing kdepimlibs5-dev. But kdepimlibs5-dev and kf5 development libraries can't co-exist.

As far as searching for other distributions such as debian, fedora,... , inserthtmldialog.h under KF5 still seems to exist, so I can not understand why ubuntu disco has deleted this file. How can I fix this problem?

I must fix it for building blogilo.

Comment: Your question seems legit but the software is in "universe" so you should ask the maintainers.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories ". Canonical does not provide a guarantee of regular security updates for software in the universe component, but will provide these where they are made available by the community. " I would file a bug report if I was you. Looks like a regression to me if it is indeed not compatible with kdepimlibs5-dev

Comment: okay, though I don't know where to send a report, (ask ubuntu(here), https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/, ...), I sent a report to bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/